# ASP .NET MVC Routing matches controller from Area instead of looking only in root

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a MVC project and it has controllers both outside and inside areas.
I have this rule in RouteConfig:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{culture}/{controller}/{action}",
                defaults: new { culture = "en", controller = "Home", action = "Index"},
                namespaces: new[] { "MyProject.Controllers" }
```

I also have an Area named **Admin** that also has controllers. There is a controller in this area with the name **AccountsController**.

It also has **AppAreaRegistration** file with this rule:

```
context.MapRoute(
                name: "Admin_default",
                url: "{culture}/admin/{controller}/{action}",
                defaults: new { culture = "en", controller = "home", action = "index" },
                namespaces: new[] { "MyProject.Areas.Admin.Controllers" }
            );
```

When I call this URL: `http://localhost/en/admin/accounts/index` my request is routed normally to `AccountsController` in `Admin` Area.

But also when I call `http://localhost/en/accounts/index` my request is again routed to `AccountsController` in `Admin` Area.

This Controller does not exist outside the `Admin Area` and the Route has namespaces defined.

I suppose that I should get a 404 response but instead I get a 500 error with the message:

```
Message: The view 'index' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:  ~/Views/accounts/index.cshtml  ~/Views/accounts/index.vbhtml  ~/Views/Shared/index.cshtml
```

How can I configure Routing to look for controllers only into the namespace defined?

Comment: WHy not defining another route as a orke around routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{culture}/admin/{controller}/{action}",
                defaults: new { culture = "en", controller = "Home", action = "Index"},
                namespaces: new[] { "MyProject.Controllers" }

Comment: Because there are many controllers in the Area and I should create a rule for each of them.

Comment: have you tried creating a normal folder @mike_x_

Comment: you can use the extension `MapAreaControllerRoute`.

Comment: Why context?  Context is usually used for a database interface and not a controller.  Do you have a two port application where one port in the client/server connection and second port the server/database interface?  Error 500 is an internal error in server after a connection completes.  Error 404 is the credentials failed.  You code is completing the credentials successfully.